# Appium with Android studio integration build error

Tags: android, android-studio, automation, appium

I am trying to integrate Appium with Android studio with version 3.0.1. I have downloaded selenium libraries from [this link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

I have downloaded appium java client from [this location](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aio.appium%20a%3Ajava-client).

Both of the downloaded JAR files, I have included as library under the project.

**First Question:**

When I try to build the project I am getting below errors

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process {location}/java-client-6.0.0-Beta2.jar
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process {location}/java_client/pagefactory/utils/WebDriverUnpackUtility.class
com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >=26)
```

**Second question:**

Also after I have downloaded selenium jar files when I try to import `org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType`, `org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities`, `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver`, `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions` all are **undefined**. But `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` is **defined**